# Why is Rav Soloveitchik's legacy so confusing?

Tags: rabbis, rav-joseph-ber-soloveitchik

I find it so peculiar how the Rav's legacy is claimed by so many.

Rabbi Meiselman claims that the Rav was practically Haredi, most consider him revisionist.

My father who sat in his shiur tells me that he was far from the present day YU hashkafa - but others tell me otherwise.

His children were fuming at David Holzer for "thinking out loud" which did just that; publicize private conversations of the Rav. They claim he too was revisionist. But Holzer told me personally that the Rav was not as they make him seem, after all he was meshamesh him for many years (Holzer is by no means Haredi.)

Avi Weiss also claims his movement is in line with the Rav's thought!

What's going on? Was it a strength of the Rav that he could relate to all types? A weakness that he was too vague in the delivery of his message?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is on-topic; this seems to be more about Jews and less about Judaism.

Comment: You could close it, that's fine. I guess I'm learning the proper function of this website. (It's a good question though)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant

Comment: Do I contradict myself?
Very well then I contradict myself,
(I am large, I contain multitudes.) (Whitman, Song of Myself)

Comment: This indeed is a very good question and I believe Rabbi Ahron Rakeffet addresses this in his new Rakeffet Aron

Comment: I've heard in the name of Rav Yehuda Parnes that it's because he himself had many thoughts going through his mind all the time on these hashkafic matters, and these thoughts would manifest themselves in different circumstances. I've heard Rav Herschel Schachter say a similar statement, that people just picked up on what they wanted to pick up on and that's that. I've heard Rav Meiselman say it's because "so many people heard two words from him and built castles in the sky, I had all these discussions with him in full" (paraphrase from memory).